Build a docker image for Python with Bazel Docker OCI
I’m working on a project that involves building Docker images using Python. I came across an example that uses the py_oci_image rule to construct an OCI image. Unfortunately, the example relies on code from the py_layer directory, which is part of the examples repository.
Here’s a brief overview of what the py_oci_image rule does in the example:

Constructs an OCI image named image with a base image of Ubuntu.
Sets an entry point for the image.
Defines platforms like aarch64_linux and x86_64_linux with specific OS and CPU constraints.
Includes rules for creating a tarball of the image and running container structure tests and Python tests on the image.

Is there a similar functionality or rule that I can use to achieve the same result?
Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

rules_distroless is worth looking into. https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/rules_distroless
